# Accessing info from Passport JS Auth request - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to access the email attribute of the current user on my website. Some of my code looks like this:

```
$scope.deleteit = function(data) {
        var deletepost = data;
        console.log(Auth.currentUser());
        // console.log(Auth.currentUser().email) //returns undefined
}
```

This is what the output looks like in my browser dev console:

```
Resource { $promise={...}, $resolved=false, $get=function(), more...}
```

When I click on it - in the dev console - I can see:

```
$promise

    Object { then=function(), catch=function(), finally=function()}

$resolved

    true

__v

    0

_id

    "53c3ef3f8766558e16233dd0"

email

    "xxx@gmail.com"

name

    "xxx"

provider

    "local"

role

    "user"

$delete

    function(params, success, error)

$get

    function(params, success, error)

$query

    function(params, success, error)

$remove

    function(params, success, error)

$save

    function(params, success, error)

$update

    function(params, success, error)

__proto__

    Resource { $get=function(), $save=function(), $query=function(), more...}
```

How do I access the email attribute?

BTW - I am trying to create a way to verify whether or not the owner of the post is the one who is trying to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go through the express route stuff and create a function to send `req.user.email` when necessary.